# Minimal subset of $x_1, x_2, ...., x_{100}$ that XORs to $y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a 64-bit positive integer $y$ and a set of $100$ $64$-bit positive integers: $X = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{100} \}$

I want to find a smallest possible $Z = \{z_1, z_2, \dots, z_n\}   \subset X$, such that:

$$\begin{align}
y = z_1 ⊕ z_2 ⊕ \dots ⊕ z_n
\end{align}$$

if such a $Z$ exists.

Clearly there are $2^{100}$ possible subsets of $X$, so iterating through them would take too long.

Does anyone know of, or can anyone think of, some sort of dynamic programming solution or other feasible algorithm?

Comment: Relevant: [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: @J.D.: No, I think because it's XOR and not addition that it is not NP-Complete.  I'm sure there is a solution that takes advantage of the independence of the bit positions in XOR, I just can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you introduce binary variables $c_i$ that are $1$ when $x_i\in Z$ and $0$ otherwise, you can write

$$y=\bigoplus_ic_ix_i\;.$$

This is a $64\times100$ system of linear equations over the field $\mathbb F_2$ for the $c_i$ that you can easily solve using Gaussian elimination; the number of steps is of the order of a million. If the $x_i$ have full rank $64$, which is almost certain to be the case if they're randomly chosen with uniform distribution, the solution space will have $36$ dimensions, so you just need to enumerate $2^{36}$ different solutions to find the optimal one; this is doable in reasonable time on a present-day computer.